# Windows 10, running as VirtualBox guest, does not see USB flash drive

Tags: windows, virtualbox, ubuntu-20.04

I'm running Windows 10 as a VM under VirtualBox in Ubuntu 20.04. I've put a USB flash drive in a USB socket and Ubuntu sees it Ok. Windows 10 VM doesn't see the drive, even though I've enabled USB 'passthrough' in VirtualBox: in other words, VirtualBox sees the drive but the Windows 10 VM doesn't. Also, Ubuntu 20.04 sees the phone the using Nautilus (the equivalent of File Explorer). Native Windows 10 sees the drive. I've looked at Device Manager and against the USB Mass Storage Device (in USB Serial Bus Controllers) there's a yellow triangle with an exclamation mark against it. I've tried right clicking the entry and uninstalling it, rebooting Windows and installing it again but I get nowhere. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you attached the device to the VM? That does not happen without user interaction.

Comment: Did you install the guest additions?

Comment: The yellow triangle means a missing driver, which probably means that Windows is unable to identify the device as a flash drive.

Comment: Guest Additions installed in VirtualBox.
I have attached the device to the VM: using Devices menu item in VirtualBox.
The driver USBStore.sys is there: name USBStore.sys obtained in native Windows 10by right clicking on USB Mass Storage device in Device Manager etc. That file is in Windows 10 VM.

Comment: I forgot to say that the Properties of the USB Mass Storage Device say "This device cannot start. (Code 10), An invalid parameter was passed to a service or function.".

Answer (score 4):

You are probably using the default USB version 1.1 instead of version
2.0 or 3.0.

To enable USB support guest machine, you must first install
The Extension Pack *on the Host machine*:

- Shutdown the VM
- Download on host the
  [VirtualBox Extension Pack](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)
- When download is completed, double click to launch the installer
  `Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-6.x.x.x.vbox-extpack`
- Follow the on-screen instructions to install the Extension Pack
- Start VirtualBox
- Select the VM and then Settings
- Choose USB at the left pane
- At the right pane, check USB 2.0 (or USB 3.0)
- Click OK
- Attach the USB device.

For more information with screenshots see
[How to Setup USB on VirtualBox Guest](https://www.wintips.org/how-to-setup-usb-on-virtualbox-guest-oracle/).

Comment: I have the Extension Pack installed. VirtualBox Settings shows USB 1.1 radio button 'checked but the 'Enable USB', USB 2.0 & USB 3.0 radio buttons are greyed out so I cannot change to USB 3.0 in Settings as advised in the previously referred to link. I have a USB filter titled MyUSBDisk with Vendor ID of 26bd & Product ID of 9917 installed (called MyUSBDisk) which are the settings for the USB flash drive from lusb Terminal command in Ubuntu 20.04).

Comment: Try to delete all filters.

Comment: I've deleted the only filter i.e. the one that I created. However, the 'Enable USB', USB 2.0 & USB 3.0 radio buttons are still greyed out

Comment: Something might be wrong with the installation of the Extension Pack?

Comment: The Extension Pack is usable.
john@desktop:~$ VBoxManage list extpacks
Extension Packs: 2
Pack no. 0:   Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack
Version:      6.1.32
Revision:     149290
Edition:      
Description:  Oracle Cloud Infrastructure integration, USB 2.0 and USB 3.0 Host Controller, Host Webcam, VirtualBox RDP, PXE ROM, Disk Encryption, NVMe.
VRDE Module:  VBoxVRDP
Usable:       true 
Why unusable:

Comment: USB 2.0/3.0 should have been available, if you're using the latest versions. Very strange.

Comment: I've just posted this as a bug using ubuntu-bug:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/virtualbox/+bug/1965628

Answer (score 2):

The Windows VM has to be Powered Off (Not Shutdown or Saved). The USB 2.0 & USB 3.0 & USB 2.0 radio buttons then appear in VirtualBox's menu Settings->USB. I selected USB 3.0 and then my USB stick & Android Phone were then 'seen' by Windows' File Explorer after enabling each one in the menu entry for Devices->USB.